# Build an interactive tree graph in python using PyQtGraph

Tags: python, plot, pyqt, plotly, pyqtgraph

I have to represent a directory structure as a graph using PyQt. e.g. Inside the 'Main' directory I have some files along with few other directories viz 'Inbox', 'Sent', 'Outbox', etc. These sub-directories will consist of emails downloaded from an IMAP server. The user should definitely have the access to drag and pull nodes (especially the leaves).

I referred to the example set of PyQt but did not find any such example where I can dynamically add a node and edge to the graph. Although, I saw an example at [Bezier curve with control points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173146/how-can-i-draw-nodes-and-edges-in-pyqt) but could not figure out a way.

All the examples in PyQt example set usually accept a numpy array as an input, and plots it to x & y coordinates of a 2D graph. I am not sure how to map directories with a numpy array, as I do not intend to plot using coordinates. The example code from PyQt looks like:

```
## Define positions of nodes
pos = np.array([[0,0],[10,0],[0,10],[10,10],[5,5],[15,5]])

## Define the set of connections in the graph
adj = np.array([[0,1],[1,3],[3,2],[2,0],[1,5],[3,5],])

## Define the symbol to use for each node (this is optional)
symbols = ['o','o','o','o','t','+']

## Define the line style for each connection (this is optional)
lines = np.array([(255,0,0,255,1),(255,0,255,255,2),(255,0,255,255,3),
       (255,255,0,255,2),(255,0,0,255,1),(255,255,255,255,4),],
       dtype=[('red',np.ubyte),('green',np.ubyte), ('blue',np.ubyte), 'alpha',np.ubyte),('width',float)])

## Update the graph
g.setData(pos=pos, adj=adj, pen=lines, size=1, symbol=symbols, pxMode=False)
```

To present what I meant, I created a simple non-interactive plot using Plotly. The direcory Inbox and Outbox will have subdirectories as well. 
[image: Directory structure].

Can anybody help me implementing the same using PyQt without showing any axes on the graph or point to me to some other resource?